# Word suddenly using relative path for hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, hyperlink

Until recently, a fellow Word 2013 user was having no trouble inserting hyperlinks with **absolute** paths into documents. The Insert Hyperlink dialog looked like this:

[image: absolute link]

Now, without changing any options, Word is inserting relative hyperlinks instead:

[image: relative link]

If they paste an absolute address into the "Address" box, Word treats it as an absolute address. The problem occurs when **selecting from the list** in the dialog.

Relevant options I know of:

- Hyperlink Base is blank, but it always has been without any problems.
- "Update links on save" is **not** checked.

Additional information: If they set Hyperlink Base to "x" in a document, then selecting from the dialog behaves as it used to--Word inserts the full path. Why should this suddenly be necessary when it was working in the past?

Using Word 2013 on Windows 10.

Note that the popular [KB903163 article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/903163) does **not** apply to Word 2013.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: *Additional information:* This behavior is documented. See KB903163.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. I want to know why the behavior of the file selection dialog changed. The hyperlink base had always been blank, and "Update links on save" has always been unchecked, and Word was inserting absolute hyperlinks, then suddenly it began using relative hyperlinks.

Comment: It has been a long time, but this problem came up again. I'd like to point out that the KB article 903163 says it applies to Word 2000-2010, **not** 2013.

Comment: Does the methods described in KB for Word2010 does NOT help in 2013?

Comment: Putting "x" in hyperlink base works, but everyone would have to remember to do that for every document. I spent several hours checking the setting of "Update links on save," and it doesn't seem to do anything, whether it is checked or not. Navigating to the target via the Insert Hyperlink dialog always results in a relative hyperlink. I have to paste the full path from somewhere else (like Windows Explorer).